# How does std::cout declaration work?

Tags: c++, cout

The `std::cout` object is declared in the `iostream` header file as

```
namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
...
extern ostream cout;
...
}
```

From now on I'm dropping the `std::` prefix.

So, as far as I understand, `cout` is "just" an object of type `ostream`. I started to wonder why stuff is printed to screen with `cout` and not with other `ostream` objects, so I tried to create an object of type `ostream`, but the compiler would not let me. As a matter of fact, `ostream` is just an alias for `basic_ostream<char>`, and the default constructor for that type is protected. Fine, I thought. But then I wondered: why is the declaration of `cout` legal to start with? Why doesn't that issue a compiler error?

I tried again to declare an `ostream` with the keyword `extern`, such as

```
extern ostream os;
os << "Will you compile?\n";
```

and this time I got the undefined reference error to os. Then the question just moves to the following: is there a 'definition' of `cout` somewhere else? If so, where?

I can't get my head around this. I know that, for performance and safety reasons, the standard header are written in a kind of "cryptic" way, not always easy to read unless you fully and completely master the language (which I still don't probably), but I'd like to understand this bit.

Thanks.

Comment: Huh what?? Where did you actually Define `os`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nowhere, hence the linker error mentioned in the question.

Comment: The `extern` keyword means that the variable in question is defined elsewhere and the compiler doesn't need to worry about where until linking time. So, to answer "is there a 'definition' of `cout` somewhere else?" Yes, there has to be.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wandering in the dark. But I guess that `cout` is then defined somewhere else...Where though?

Comment: @bartgol It's provided with `lstdc++`, which is linked automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I started to wonder why stuff is printed to screen with cout and not with other ostream objects,

Because `std::cout` uses a stream buffer that is associated with the `stdout` device.

> so I tried to create an object of type ostream, but the compiler would not let me. As a matter of fact, ostream is just an alias for basic_ostream, and the default constructor for that type is protected. Fine, I thought. But then I wondered: why is the declaration of cout legal to start with? Why doesn't that issue a compiler error?

Because it's a declaration, not a definition, so it doesn't invoke any constructor. Maybe you should read about what `extern` means on a declaration.

The declaration with `extern` just says there is an object defined somewhere else in the program that is of type `ostream` and called `cout`. Since you didn't actually provide any such definition you get linker errors.

To approximately simulate `std::cout` you could do this in some `.cpp` file:

```
namespace {
  std::ofstream fake_cout("/dev/stdout");
}
std::ostream cout(fake_cout.rdbuf());
```

This creates an `fstream` that writes to `/dev/stdout` then associates the `ostream` called `cout` with its stream buffer.

This isn't a good simulation of the real `std::cout` because it doesn't ensure that the stream is initialized before any other globals try to use it, which the real one does.

Comment: Thanks for the example! For some reason I did not think that the definition of cout is in some source (or the library) and not in the headers. Of course I could not find it!

Your example is very helpful, cause it also made me discover the stdout/err/in inside the /dev folder (I still have to learn a lot about the unix system and root tree).

Thanks!

Comment: Also, why is the `std::cout` guaranteed to initialize the stream before any other global tries to use it while my personal implementation wouldn't?

Comment: Because the order of initialization of globals in different objects is unspecified, see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order The standard library takes special precautions to ensure `std::cin`, `std::cout` and `std::cerr` are initialized before objects that try to use them, typically using a [Schwarz Counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter).

Answer (score 4):

> is there a 'definition' of cout somewhere else? If so, where?

Yes, there is a definition of `cout` in the libstdc++ implementation of the standard C++ library. This definition is not done in a way that's valid in standard C++. That's okay, because the implementation of the standard C++ library doesn't have to be written in standard C++, it just has to be written in a way that the rest of the implementation understands.

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed wondering where that definition was, since it was not in the c++ include folder, where all the standard headers are. But it makes sense: it is declared in the standard headers, and defined in the sources (that is, in the libstdc++ library), where it is created using the buffer of the OS.

Now it's clear. I was missing the fact that the std library does not come just with headers but also with...a library! =)